# Apply unique twice in groupby dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
key_1, key_2, country
12, a, US
12, a, US
12, b, US
12, c, NZ
23, d, PE
23, e, PE
23, e, PE
31, f, RO
31, f, RO
42, g, VI
```

I'm interested in 2 dataframes (please provide one procedure for each dataframe) that fulfill the following conditions:

1st- given a key_1, there are more than one unique key_2 `AND` one unique country. For example.

```
23, d, PE
23, e, PE
```

2nd- given a key_1, there are more than one unique key_2 `AND` more than one unique country. For example.

```
12, a, US
12, b, US
12, c, NZ
```

In both cases, the resulting dataframes should have unique rows.

Been reading other questions for a while now but the closest I've got is:

```
result = df.groupby("key_1")["key_2"].apply(pd.value_counts).count(level=0)
```

Which helps me find which rows have more than one unique "`key_2` per `key_1`" (most of my dataframe is made of a unique key_2 and country per key_1 rows, regardless of duplicated) but I'm still far from what I need.

Thank you very much in advance! (sorry for the question title but I'm not sure what to call this)

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours digging around I finally managed to do it myself. Anyone with a better solution is welcome to answer!

I've tried the following code on my real dataframe and it works.

As @Alexander pointed out correctly, "both of your desired dataframes are built on the same set of data: rows with more than one key_2 for a given key_1"

Therefore I'm first subsetting for rows that have more than one unique key_2 given a key_1. Then I will split it into 2: One for a unique country given a key_1, and another one for more than 2 countries given a key_1.

```
# more than one unique key_2 per key_1
subset_k2= df.groupby(['key_1'])['key_2'].nunique().reset_index()
subset_k2= subset_gb[subset_gb[key_2] > 1]
subset_all= df[df["key_1"].isin(subset_k2["key_1"].tolist())]

# more than one unique country per key_1
subset_ct= df.groupby(['key_1'])['country'].nunique().reset_index()
subset_ct= subset_ct[subset_ct['country'] > 1]

# Results that fulfill condition 2 from my question:
result_2 = subset_all[subset_all["key_1"].isin(subset_ct["key_1"].tolist())].drop_duplicates()

# Results that fulfill condition 1 from my question:
result_1 = subset_all[~subset_all["key_1"].isin(subset_ct["key_1"].tolist())].drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_groups and the drop_duplicates:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby("key_1")

In [12]: g.get_group(12).drop_duplicates()
Out[12]:
   key_1 key_2 country
0     12     a      US
2     12     b      US
3     12     c      NZ

In [13]: g.get_group(23).drop_duplicates()
Out[13]:
   key_1 key_2 country
4     23     d      PE
5     23     e      PE
```

Comment: thank you! I guess I should have mentioned my real df has about 300k rows so it wouldn't be practical this way. Also, what I'm looking for is a "query" or "method" to apply to the whole df and return the desired subset. e.g. df.method_1 = subset_1, df.method_2 = subset_2

Comment: Why wouldn't it be practical? get_groups is very efficient, and will do 300k easy. The other option is dropping first `g = df.drop_duplicates().groupby("key_1")`. I guess it depends what you're doing with these results...

Comment: it seems I can't edit my own question =(. What I would like from the df are two subsets. One for each logic outlined above. For example results_1_df could be: 23, d, PE / 
23, e, PE / 51, h, UR / 51, i, UR / 63, j, US / 63, k, US. i.e. several key_1s in results_1_df

Comment: but why do that? That's always going to be less efficient than a groupby

Comment: source: df (300k rows) / objective: results_1_df (about 1,000 rows, of which about 400 are unique key_1). /// group_by() queries one key_1 at a time, and I need to tell it which key_1 I'm querying right?

Comment: 300k is not that many, I'm not sure where you're coming from. Like I say, it depends what your end game is, atm this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My answer optimizes lookups which is what you seemed to be asking. If it's a calculation you'll want to use a groupby method...

Answer (score 0):

Both of your desired dataframes are built on the same set of data:  rows with more than one `key_2` for a given `key_1`.

First, we'll group on `key_1` and count the `key_2` values.  We create a list called `keys` where the `key_2` count is greater than one.

These keys are then used to filter the original dataframe.

Next, we merge the country count (grouped on `key_1` and `key_2`) to the dataframe.

Finally, we split this dataframe based on it's `country_count` value (i.e. equal to one and greater than one).

```
from collections import Counter

# Create sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'key_1': [12,12,12,12,23,23,23,31,31,42], 
                   'key_2': list('aabcdeeffg'), 
                   'country': ['US', 'US', 'US', 'NZ', 'PE', 'PE', 'PE', 'RO', 'RO', 'VI']})

# Get list of key pairs where there are more than one `key_2` for a given `key_1`
gb1 = df.groupby(['key_1', 'key_2']).key_2.count()
keys = gb1[gb1 > 1].index.tolist()

# Filter the dataframe for the correct keys.
idx = [n for n, pair in enumerate(zip(df.key_1, df.key_2)) if pair in keys]
df_temp = df.ix[idx]

# Get the country count for each `key_`1 / `key_2' pair.
gb1 = df_temp.groupby('key_1').key_2.apply(Counter)
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(gb1.reset_index().values, columns=['key_1', 'key_2', 'country_count'])
df_temp = df.merge(df_temp, on=['key_1', 'key_2'])

# More than one unique `key_2` for a given `key_1` and only one country.
df1 = df_temp.loc[df_temp.country_count == 1, ['key_1', 'key_2', 'country']]

# More than one unique `key_2` for a given `key_1` and more than one country.
df2 = df_temp.loc[df_temp.country_count > 1, ['key_1', 'key_2', 'country']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempt. Unfortunately I wasn't getting the results expected with your procedure =( . For df1 I was getting key_1, key_2 and country all empty. For df2 I was getting some key_1 and key_2 but all country were NaN.